# Unable to call a jQuery function outside the jQuery(function(){}); body

Tags: jquery, referenceerror

I am creating a jQuery to create a custom designs. All my functions are running under `jQuery(function(){})` body, like:

```
  jQuery(function(){
       abc();
       function abc(){
          alert('Test');
       }   
  });
```

This code is working but when I want to call this function on another page after including this file then this give me "ReferenceError: abc is not defined".

Anyone can tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: have you included this script in the second page as well..? are you calling this function anywhere else in second page?

Comment: Yes I have added my script on second page. Yes I am calling this function on four different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is created in an other function, so it is only accessible there.

you could do something like this:

```
var abc;
jQuery(function(){

    abc = function(){
          alert('Test');
    }  
    abc(); 
  });
```

some where in the page:

```
jQuery(function(){
    abc();
});
```

Comment: or move function declaration out of the ready handler closure compeletely